# svnx or rapid svn?

Tags: svn, macos

I want to know which software I should use for subversion on Mac OS X. I have been using svnX but somebody told me to use RapidSVN as it is more user friendly and better, but I don't like it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Old answer

Not finding any appropriate answer so sticking with svnX.

---

#### Editing after 4 years (new answer)

During this whole period I have only learned that don't use GUI tool for svn or git. Command line tools gives you more power and the are the same commands on all the platforms you don't have to seek different GUI tools for different platforms if you know the command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)?

Comment: Nope I don't use it...Is It better one??

Comment: I've been using it now for the last month and I must say, it's great.

Comment: I have downloaded it, but it's a trial version

Comment: If it's worth it, you can consider purchasing it. You'll answer your questions by e-mail efficiently.

Comment: +1 to Versions.  I've been using it for years and it is great.  It is reliable and the UI is nicely done.  SvnX and RapidSVN both pale in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use that one in which you fell comfortable all client svn are almost the same

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion - if you are looking for a great svn client the check cornerstone - http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php